# Why do I have to press two times CTRL+[ to come back from VISUAL to NORMAL mode in vi?

Tags: vim, vi-mode

Is there a simpler way to come back to NORMAL mode in vi?

The answer that has just been deleted mentioned 'delay'. I pressed CTRL+[ only once and it really brought me back to NORMAL mode after some delay. It seems that I just wasn't patient enough. However it's not clear why it takes so long.

PS: Other mode transitions are very quick...

Comment: Under the default configuration, you only need to press `ESC` (or `Ctrl+[`, but what vi user uses `Ctrl+[`???) once and wait for about a second. What happens when you press `Ctrl+[` a single time? If it doesn't return you to visual mode, what did you put in your `.vimrc` to change this?

Comment: @roaima Yes, more and more laptops/tablets lack ESC, but I can't imagine any vi user using such a keyboard without remapping `` or Tab or CapsLock or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason there has to be a delay after hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> is that it's not only a standalone key in `vi` that returns from INSERT mode to COMMAND mode, it's also generated via a terminal (emulation) as the prefix for many function keys.

For example, on my keyboard right now <kbd>F1</kbd> generates the hex sequence *1b 4f 50*. The first of those (*1b*) is <kbd>Esc</kbd>. Cursor right is *1b 5b 43*. Escape by itself is *1b*.

`vi` handles the differentiation by assuming that for a compound key sequence all the characters will come rapidly, but for a single use of <kbd>Esc</kbd> there will be a small pause after the character.